# Change style based on data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

Consider below XAML =>

```
        <fluent:Ribbon x:Name="MenuRibbon"
                       Title="title"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <fluent:RibbonTabItem x:Name="Home"
                                  Header="Home">
            <fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Project">
                <fluent:InRibbonGallery MinItemsInRow="3"
                                            MaxItemsInRow="6"
                                            Width="300"
                                            ItemWidth="64"
                                            ItemHeight="56"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
                    <fluent:InRibbonGallery.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Height="56">

                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                               Text="{Binding Name}">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </fluent:InRibbonGallery.ItemTemplate>
                </fluent:InRibbonGallery>
            </fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
        </fluent:RibbonTabItem>
    </fluent:Ribbon>
```

I've bind ObservableColleciton of Projects to InRibbonGallery , And there is an instance of project (ActiveProject) exist in ViewModel.

a TextBlock defined in DataTemplate to display Name of Project object.
How can I change color of TextBlock that contains Active Project ? 
ViewModel :

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Project> _projects;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>(new List<Project>
                                                         {
                                                             new Project {Id = "0", Name = "Project1"},
                                                             new Project {Id = "1", Name = "Project2"},
                                                             new Project {Id = "2", Name = "Project3"}
                                                         });
        Project = Projects[0];
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return _projects; }
        set
        {
            _projects = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Projects);
        }
    }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class Project : ObservableObject
{
    private string _id;
    private string _name;

    public string Name

    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Project files located [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54490657/Stackoverflow/WpfApplication1.zip) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a `MultiBinding` and a `DataTrigger` in combination for a better result.

so your xaml would look like:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
  <vm:ActiveProjectCheckConverter x:Key="ActiveProjectCheckConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            Text="{Binding Name}">
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Transparent" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ActiveProjectCheckConverter}">
              <Binding Path="Name" />
              <Binding Path="DataContext.ActiveProject.Name"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                        AncestorType={x:Type fluent:InRibbonGallery}}" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </DataTrigger.Binding>
          <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
              <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0"
                              Color="#00FFFFFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.1"
                              Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
              </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

and your converter:

```
public class ActiveProjectCheckConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    string first = values[0] as string;
    string second = values[1] as string;
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(first) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(second) && first == second;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Now I did make one more change, your Project object in your ViewModel, if you want changes to that to reflect in the View you need to make that implement INPC itself. So I did update that and also renamed it to `ActiveProject`

```
private Project _activeProject;

public Project ActiveProject {
  get {
    return _activeProject;
  }
  set {
    if (value == _activeProject)
      return;
    _activeProject = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => ActiveProject);
  }
}
```

**Update**

You can find the above updates at: [Dropbox-Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h786xuzfftef2uv/WpfApplication1.rar)

Comment: Thanks!How can I apply more complex effect like this =>       <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0">

                                                <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />

                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1.1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>

                                        </Border.Background>

Comment: @shaahin I updated the code to not send the entire object to the converter and rather just send the Name property. I've also switched the converter to send a LinearGradientBrush like what you've posted above instead of a SolidColorBrush. You can tweak that to what you need.

Comment: Thanks again. I've accepted your answer. I just want to know is there any way write styles in XAML code and use converter to set visibility of style ? or something else that able me to write styles XAML side not in behind code .

Comment: Viv , I really appreciate your comment . As I am newbie in WPF please give me a link , article or anything would be regard your comment.

Comment: Ill update my answer in the morning. Not at my machine right now. Don't really think DataTemplateSelectors will be helpful here since ActiveProject can be updated at runtime(forgot abt that). Think we need some DataTriggers to get this. Ill try a few options and update tomorrow.

Comment: Had to come back to my machine to try this right away lol. I've updated my answer and also added a Dropbox Link you can download your project with the updates and try out. We basically use the converter to just tell us if an item is the ActiveProject and let the DataTrigger in xaml handle the styling based on the result :)